# which of the following are true related to trace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let, $A$ = ($a_i$$_j$) be a matrix of order $n$ and let $A^*$ denote the conjugate transpose of $A$. Which of the following statements are necessarily true ?

$1$. If $A$ is invertible, then $tr$ $(A^*A)$ $\neq$ $0$.

$2$. If $tr$ $(A^*A)$ $\neq$ $0$ then $A$ is invertible.

$3$. If  $|$tr$ (A^*A)|$ $<$ $n^2$, then $|a_i$$_j$| $<$ $1$ for some i,j.

$4$. If $tr$ $(A^*A)$ = $0$ , then $A$ is the zero matrix.

Comment: Try to find a formula to compute $tr(A^*A)$ in terms of the entries $a_{ij}$ of $A$.

Comment: @  daw : How? can u help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trace of $A^*A$ satisfies
$$
tr(A^*A) = \sum_{i,j=1}^n |a_{ij}|^2.
$$
This should help to prove that (1)(3)(4) are true, (2) is false.

Comment: can u help why (2) is true? @ daw

Comment: sorry, typo: 2 is false, 3 is true

Comment: ok! its fine! :)